# Quaternion lerping not working as expected in Unity with c#

Tags: c#

I have tried my own methods but I have not been able to get a method that works, here is an example gif: https://gyazo.com/5cd4b74ee45240d3ff9ee13ae6ca6af6

And here is the code that is used in that gif:

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject moving;
 
float lerpTime = 5f;
float currentLerpTime;
 
float moveDistance = 10f;
 
Quaternion startPos;
Quaternion endPos;
 
protected void Start()
{
    startPos = moving.transform.rotation;
    endPos = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
 
protected void Update()
{
    //reset when we press spacebar
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        currentLerpTime = 0f;
    }
 
    //increment timer once per frame
    currentLerpTime += Time.deltaTime;
    if (currentLerpTime > lerpTime)
    {
        currentLerpTime = lerpTime;
    }
 
    //lerp!
    float perc = currentLerpTime / lerpTime;
    print(perc);
    moving.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startPos, endPos, perc);
}
}
```

It does not change until it reaches alpha 1 and I'm not sure why.
If you have any clue why it's doing this and know how to help me please write a comment.

Comment: oops, i just changed the end goal and it worked

Comment: Hi Daniel Wallace, welcome to stackoverflow. You can write an answer to your own question. Please describe what you changed and how it did change the desired behaviour. It might be helpful for others.